Why is the strlen here equal to 25?
Just so I can confirm if what I think is going on is really going on. The following code prints out 25 when i give it the (26 letter) alphabet as an input, is it 'cause fgets always automatically sets the nth element in an array of n elements to be '\n'?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[26];

    printf("String: ");
    fgets(str, 26, stdin);

    printf("%lu\n", strlen(str));
}


That way when I try to print the strlen of the alphabet it stops right before the '\n' and returns me 25?

fgets() does not "automatically set the nth element to \n". It read all characters from the input, up to the buffer size given or up to (and including) the newline. Again, fgets() does not "add a newline". It just reads the input. If the input contains no newline, then neither will the buffer.

The root of the problem is that you think you can store a string of 26 letters in an array of size 26. That's not how strings work in C, fgets or no fgets.

If the entire line fits in the buffer, according to your size argument (26 in your case), which includes the string null-terminator, then fgets will add the newline.
If the full line does not fit in the buffer, then fgets will not add a newline, only as much as can fit in the buffer (including the null-terminator).
So, if you input anything more than 25 characters (newline excluded) then the length will always be 25.

On a different note, you should always check what fgets returns.
And the strlen function returns a value of type size_t for which the correct printf format is %zu.
And if possible, use sizeof when using fgets. As in fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin).

+1 for newline. You had not forgot, that 26-symbol entry from terminal also contains a newline symbol(s) so we get 26+1 or 2+1 = 29 symbols array required

"then fgets will add the newline." --> more like "then fgets will read and save the 'z' and newline."

OP entered: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" Enter. That is 27 characters: Characters 'a' to 'z' and the line-feed '\n'.
fgets(str, 26, stdin); reads up to 25 characters from stdin and then appends a null character, '\0'.
Therefore strlen(str) is 25 and "z\n" remain in stdin to read later.

Instead read into larger buffer and lop off a potential trailing '\n'.
// Large enough for 26 letters, \n, appended \0
char str[           26          +1       +1];

printf("String: ");
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
  printf("%zu\n", strlen(str));   // Expect 27. Note specifier changed to %zu.
  str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential trailing '\n'.
  printf("%zu\n", strlen(str));   // Expect 26
}


You are thinking in the right direction.
You may check the docs (it is ok to use cpp docs for c in most cases):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets
It states, that the signature is:
char* fgets(char* str, int count, FILE* stream);

Docs say:

Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and
stores them in the character array pointed to by str.

Therefore you give it a 26-element array, it fills it with up to 25 elements and appends terminator. In C terminator is a zero-byte ('\0').
strlen in fact searches for the next terminator after the given address. It finds that str[25] == '\0' and returns 25 as the result.
That place is a large security problem in some applications - you should always add one extra item in char array for terminator, if you plan to use char* as null-terminated C-string. Otherwise all functions will not stop processing at the end of the string - they operate only on the pointer and there is no len argument given in most cases.
Is that always the case?
There are usecases, where null-character is not used as terminator and even it can be a part of data, but in such cases you should not call this array a "string". In some protocols you have length of the char array listed elsewhere. For example see BER-TLV. It contains concatenated tag number, length and array itself. Here is and example or "123" contained in tag 0x55:
55 03 31 32 33

31 32 33 - 3 bytes in ASCII, that represent "123". See - no null-terminator!
While such formats are widely used in communication, you can not use pointer to such an array as an argument in strlen or printf.
Thanks to @some-programmer-dude. I have to mention that:
When you enter some string into terminal, you terminate that entry with the carriage return (newline). In Linux it is just "\n" (1 byte), while on Windows it is "\r\n" (2 bytes).
Let's say you entered John and pressed Enter. Stream will contain:
"John\n" - that is 5 bytes. But to store this text and use it in printf's %s substitution or, say, strlen, you should also store a floating null-terminator. So you may want to allocate at least 6 bytes:
str[6] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\n', '\0'};

When you call strlen, it will return count of non-zero elements since given pointer - that will be 5.
If you then will reuse that array and store, for example just "?", than you will have:
str[6] = {'?', '\n', '\0', 'n', '\n', '\0'};

Note, that strlen will return 2, while array is not cleared after the \0. All functions will ignore the data after the first detected '\0' character and printf (for example) will "see" only "?\n".
